# Нужно второе тире или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Какой вариант пунктуации в предложении верен и почему?

**Государственная Дума является палатой Федерального Собрания — парламента Российской Федерации (—) и состоит из 450 депутатов.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Государственная Дума является палатой Федерального Собрания — парламента Российской Федерации и состоит из 450 депутатов.**

Пояснение

Это тема обособленных приложений, где рассматриваются случаи постановки одного тире.

Федеральное собрание Российской Федерации — это парламент Российской Федерации, представительный и законодательный орган государственной власти.
Таким образом, один и тот же государственный орган имеет **два названия,** поэтому **нежелательно придавать второму названию уточняющий (присоединительный)  характер.**

Первое название (федеральное собрание) более официальное, но и второе название (парламент) также используется достаточно часто.

Если поставить два тире, то в виде пояснения будут обозначены только парламентские функции этого органа.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Примечание. **Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:**
2) если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение: На совещании министров иностранных дел стран — членов Организации американских государств выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.); Высшая награда Французского института океанографии за выдающиеся океанографические работы — медаль в память Альберта I принца Монакского присуждена видному учёному Л. А. Зенькевичу (Газ.);

Comment: У меня путаница в голове. Почему здесь два тире: *Статья 94 
Федеральное Собрание - парламент Российской Федерации - является представительным и законодательным органом Российской Федерации.* (http://www.constitution.ru/10003000/10003000-7.htm)

Comment: Встречаются оба варианта записи.  Они оба правильны, но выражают разные смысловые оттенки, об этом подробно сказано в ответе.